# Farm solution deployed to my web application , is not available to new site collections

Tags: 2013, development, solution-package, farm-solution, custom-web-parts

I have a .wsp Farm solution deployed to my web applications, as follow:-

[image]

[image]

I have created this solution using VS .Now inside my current web application I have 2 site collections. Old site collection have this solution available under “Insert>>Web Part>>Custom” + inside the “Site Setting>>Web designer Galery>>Web parts”  as follow:-

[image]

But now I added a new site collection to my web application , but the problem I am facing is that the .wsp solution is not available inside the “Insert>>Web Part>>Custom” Nor inside the “Site Setting>>Web designer Galery>>Web parts”  as follow:-

[image]

Can anyone advice please? Could this be a version problem ? since I have applied some CU updates from the time I deployed he wsp and when I added the new site collection ? can anyone advice please?

**EDIT:-**

Here are the web part setting inside the visual studio:-

[image]

now the site URL refers to an old site URL. Now I have deploied this wsp using the following steps:-

- i copy the wsp from the visual studio project.
- Then i run the following commad:-
  "stsadm -o addsolution –filename [c:....]\WikiKnowledgeBaseRedirect.wsp"
- i went to "central administration>>system settings>> Manage farm solutions>>click on WikiKnowledgeBaseRedirect>>click on deploy solution >>select the web application from the “Deploy To?" drop down". and it became available to my old site collection which have the following URL "`http://servername/Site/Customes`" different from the site URL inside the visual studio. so seems the site URL inside the visual studio do not have any value ? is this correct?

here is the feature screen as requested :-

[image]
ok it mentioned that its scope is site, then why it did not appear inside the site collection feature or inside the gallery>>web parts section?

**EDIT 2**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please upload the feature screen in visual studio?

Comment: @AmalHashim thanks i have uploaded the screen, now it mentioned that the scope=site. so why it did not appear inside the site collection>>gallery>web parts ?

Comment: Ok. Now open the new Site Collection features page (not site features) and check if you can see feature with name `WikiKnowledgeBaseRedirect Feature1`.

Comment: yes i already checked it , and it is not there. even on the site collection which have this feature inside the "WikiKnowledgeBaseRedirest Feature1" is only avilable insdie the "site setting>>web designer gallery>>web parts"..can u adivce ?

Comment: so should i "Site URL" inside the visual studio match the real URL , as in my case this  URL reflects the test server url, but when i deploy the solution using "-stadm" it worked well inside my old site collection which have URL such as "servername/knowledge/customers" while the site url inside visual studio is "servername/wikilibrary"?

Comment: Only feature activation will place the webpart in the gallery.

Comment: But it is not available inside the gallery nor inside the site collection features ... can the site url be the problem ? Altohugh I do not think so because the old site collection have different url from what is specified inside the VS project and it worked well...

Comment: @AmalHashim can you advice on this please

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your sitecollection features page

Comment: @AmalHashim i have added the full site collection features sections (inside Edit2 section). can you check them please ?

Comment: Can you see a feature with name "WikiKnowledgeBaseRedirect Feature1"

Comment: no as i mentioned bore there is no feature named "WikiKnowledgeBaseRedirect Feature1". and even on the old site collection which have this feature under "Custom web parts", the "WikiKnowledgeBaseRedirect Feature1" exists only inside the web part gallery and not inside the site collection features section

Comment: Can you see that feature in your old site collection?

Comment: yes but it appear under the "site setting>>Web gallery>>web parts" and not inside the site collection features. and i was able to add this as a custom web part inside my pages..

Comment: now i think this might be the problem or part of it, is that inside the VS i defined the scope to be "Site" level, while on the live server i deploy it to my web application level?what do you think ?

Comment: @AmalHashim can you advice please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19145/discussion-between-amal-hashim-and-john-g).

Answer (score 1):

The webpart is deployed as part of a feature. Activate the feature in new site collection and then the webpart will be available.

Comment: but the feature is not available in the site collection features. i went to "Site settings>>site collection features", there is no feature for the related wsp ? can you adivce ?

Comment: In visual studio check which feature the webpart is associated with. Then check the scope of that feature. Then make sure that feature is deployed.

Comment: also inside the site collection which have this feature deployed the wsp is not listed inside the "site collection features",instead it is listed inside the "Web Designer Gallery"... i am now confused..

Comment: now when i first deploy the wsp . i did the following steps:- I run the following "stsadm -o addsolution –filename [c:\....]\WikiKnowledgeBaseRedirect.wsp"

Go to central administration>>system settings>> Manage farm solutions>>click on WikiKnowledgeBaseRedirect>>click on deploy solution >>select the web application from the “Deploy To?" drop down. and it became available to my old site collection.

Comment: Your old site collection will get this automatically because it was previous deployed and feature got activated. Try to directly deploy the solution from Visual Studio. And set the SiteURl as the new site collection.

Comment: can you check my edit section to the original question?